# Adding Subscriber via MailChimp API

Tags: mailchimp

I'm adding a subscriber to a list using the MailChimp API. I'm receiving back the euid and the leid values. However, if I take to the account, I don't see the subscriber. I thought maybe there a delay, but the history showing my API calls is correctly reflecting a correct response back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when this happens, it's because the subscription is done with double opt-in turned on. In API v3, you'll want to use `status` 'subscribed' instead of 'pending'. In previous versions, set the `double_optin` to false.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that.

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks!

Comment: There is a delay of a few minutes before the list counter is updated, some caching on the API end. I used a call to check subscription status first. Seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a kind of an answer to this problem in case someone should need it. Apparently the time it takes to show the added subscribers is due to some API cache as @Louis Ferreira pointed, to make the aggregate of the subscribers to the created list instantaneous, without having to wait for those extra minutes, another list can be created without subscribers just after adding the subscribers to the first list. This makes the cache to update and your subscribers will be updated immediately. Then using the same API you can delete this second list created preventing unused lists accumulation. I hope this helps someone out there.